# User Deleted, but Question remains and user would like to re-associate

Tags: support, status-completed, account

In reference to: [How to analyse data/voice ratio within a network](https://serverfault.com/q/453069/33417)

I can't tell what happened here, but the user account doesn't exist anymore. The user just asked the question yesterday, it wasn't migrated, none of the "normal" reasons for not having at least an unregistered account apply (that I'm aware of).

Further, the user wants to edit his question, comment, etc; re-associate with the Question. Even mods can't arbitrarily assign ownership of a question. So ... what now??

Comment: Find someone to run some SQL.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention?  Oh, wait...  Seems like a job for team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: He could just earn enough rep on somewhere so that he can add comments to any question, then not worry about it?

Comment: Looks like he might have deleted his own account. There's ambiguous language describing if a user is able to delete their own account or not. But it fits the scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure *what* went wrong here, but something did. There was a merge on the user account that somehow orphaned this question. I fixed that up, so the user should have access to the question once again.

In general, we ([the community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do)) have the ability to (dis)associate posts, so feel free to hunt one of us down to do the honours. There are usually a couple of us hanging out in the Teacher's Lounge.

Comment: Perfecta. I know I've seen this at least once before, but it's been a while. Obviously not a common problem. Thank you!